Open immersions stable under base change proof
I am having trouble with proving a simple statement (open immersions are stable under base change) and I don't know where to start. The proof my professor wrote goes like this: let $f: X \to Y$ be an open immersion of schemes, and $Y' \to Y$ some morphism. Then $p_2: X \times_Y Y' \to Y'$ induces an isomorphism with $f(X) \times_Y Y' \cong p_1^{-1}(f(X))$, where $p_1$ is the first projection map of $p_1: Y \times_Y Y' \to Y$. I know that $Y \times_Y Y' \cong Y'$, but I am having trouble piecing these data together to prove that we have an open immersion.
I read online that we have an induced morphism $f': X \times_Y Y' \to Y \times_Y Y'$ given by $f \times id_{Y'}$. But I don't see why it is clear that this would be an open immersion.

Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883958/open-immersions-stable-under-base-change

I think this is too basic to prove without knowing exactly how you construct $X \times_Y Y'$ or define "open immersion".

Thanks, I'm going to stare at this for a bit longer. I will go see the TA next week to ask about this and will post and update if it is resolved.
